# Netlogo- Creating agents with traits from .csv files

Tags: csv, netlogo

I'm attempting to populate my world with agents whose traits are from a csv file. The file looks like this: [image: file]

I'm pretty fluent in other areas of NetLogo but this is the first time diving in to external data inputs.

I've looked in other places but and other topics are only for populating a list of data. The official help and dictionary seem to have big differences pre-and post- v 5.1 so I'm not sure if the help guides I'm finding are accurate to the latest version.

I don't even particularly care if a large list (or list of lists) is produced  or if while reading the data line-by-line, it wipes the previous lines' data after producing an agent.

I've tried using the help given here: http://netlogoabm.blogspot.com/2015/05/connecting-or-linking-turtles-from-csv.html

but that seems to throw errors since my data is not only numbers. I would really appreciate assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can modify my example to match your problem, in summary I first read the file into a global list, extracted the number of agents, assigned properties of agents at each tick and ran the simulation:

```
 extensions [csv]
    Breed [Drivers Driver]
    turtles-own[
      Name
     List-Of-Actions

    ]
    globals [li]

    to setup

      ca
      set li []
      file-open "Time.csv"
      load-Files-And-Set-The-List
    CreateDrivers
Set-Agents-List-Of-Actions
      reset-ticks
    end






    to load-Files-And-Set-The-List
      if file-at-end? [ stop file-close  ]  ;; protect against end of file


      while [not file-at-end? ]
    [
      let _line (csv:from-row file-read-line ",")
      set li lput _line li

    ]



    end




    to Set-Agents-List-Of-Actions
     let t []



      foreach li  
      [
      if position ? li > 0  
        [


          ask turtles with [Name =  (item 0 ?)]
          [
            set hidden? false
            set List-Of-Actions lput  ( list (item 1 ?) (item 2 ?) (item 3 ?)) List-Of-Actions


          ]
        ]
      ]

    end


    to go

        ask Drivers
          [
            foreach  List-Of-Actions 

            [

              if ticks = (item 0 ?)

              [

             move-to patch (item 1 ?) (item 2 ?)


              set List-Of-Actions remove ? List-Of-Actions 

              ]
            ]


          ]

     tick 
    end


    to-report Driver-Names  
      let  DriverNames  []
      foreach li 
      [
        if position ? li > 0
        [
          set DriverNames lput (item 0 ?) DriverNames 
        ]
      ]

      set DriverNames  remove-duplicates DriverNames 
      report DriverNames 

    end




    to CreateDrivers
      resize-world 0 500 0 3
      set-patch-size 60
      let n length Driver-Names 
      Foreach Driver-Names 
      [
        create-Drivers 1
        [
          set Name ?
          set shape "car"
          set size 1
          set hidden? true
          set List-Of-Actions []
        ]
      ]



    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [CSV extension](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html) read the file in easily. Then you should be able to just iterate through each line, creating a turtle and setting its variables. It's bundled with NetLogo 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the models library - code examples folder, 'File Input Example'?